# How to swizzle URLSession class method data(for:) in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, swizzle

I want to swizzle URLSession class method `data(for:)` but not been able to get it done.

I tried this swizzling in Swift but it not working, bellow is the error:

the code:
`#selector(URLSession.data(for:))`

the error:
[image]

Please help me.

---

Update 1:

My Problem:

I have swizzle URLSession with

`#selector(URLSession.dataTask(with:) as (URLSession) -> (URLRequest) -> URLSessionDataTask)`

and

`#selector(URLSession.dataTask(with:) as (URLSession) -> (URL) -> URLSessionDataTask)`.

It works fine before iOS 16+ with the follow code: `try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)`. I don't know why, So, I want swizzle the `data(for:)` method to test my guess, but it fails.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Isn't the real method `data(for:delegate:)` with default parameter to `delegate` as `nil`? But since it might need the async/await, which I'm not sure is exposed to Objective-C, maybe the old version with the completionHandler parameter?

Comment: @Sweeper Because of the URLSession swizzle does not work on iOS 16+ version when call ```URLSession.data(for: request)``` mehtod.

Comment: @Larme ```data(for:delegate:)``` was introduced into from iOS 15+, even use ```data(for:delegate:)``` that will fail

Comment: @Larme yes, it should need the async/await, and it works well on iOS 15.5, not iOS 16+. So, I want to swizzle the ```data(for:)``` for resovle this issue.